# A question based on metric space $d(x_i , y_i) $= $\sum_{i\geq 1 }|x_i -y_i| 2^{-i}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

This question was asked in my analysis quiz and I was unable to solve some options although I tried at home also.

> Question: Let X={$(x_i)_{i\geq 1}: x_i \in$ {0,1} for all$ i\geq 1 $} with metric $d(x_i , y_i)$ = $\sum_{i\geq 1 }|x_i -y_i| 2^{-i}$. Let $f: X \to [0,1]$ be the function defined by $f(x_i)_{i\geq 1} = \sum_{i\geq 1}x_i 2^{-i}$. Which of the following options are correct:

1 f is continuous.

2 f is onto

3 f is 1-1

4 f is open

I have proved 1. But I don't know how to approach 2, 4 . I proved 3 right . BUt answer doesn't have it as correct.

I hav egiven a lot of time on it. I request you to tell me 2,3,4.

Waiting for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can prove that $d$ is in fact a metric.

(1) In a metric
space $(X,d)$, the metric $d$ is continuous so that $f(x)=d(o,x)$ is
continuous where $o=(0,0,0,\cdots)$.

(2) For any $y\in [0,1]$, then we have $y= \sum_{i=1}^\infty
\frac{\varepsilon_i}{2^i},\ \varepsilon_i\in \{0,1\}$ so that
$f(\varepsilon)=y$ where $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_i)$, which proves
that $f$ is onto

(3) When $x=(1,0,0,0,\cdots ),\ y=(0,1,1,1,\cdots)$, then $f(x)=f(y)=
\frac{1}{2}$ so that not $1$-$1$.

(4) Consider a open ball $B=\{ x| d(x,y)< \frac{1}{2}\}$ where $y=
(1,0,0,0,\cdots )$

Note that $B$ is exactly the set of all points of type
$x=(1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots )$ s.t. some $x_i$ is equal to $0$

Hence $f(B) = [\frac{1}{2},1)$ is not open so that $f$ is not open

Answer (score 2):

Well, firstly, you need correct your $f$, it has to be $f(x) = \sum_{i} x_i 2^{-i}$ , i guess.

I think I encountered this one when learning contruction of $\mathbb{R}$.

2) Surjectivity is easy. In fact, if you look closely, this is in someway the formal the question of writing a real number in binary system.
So, loosely, we have for $1 > x \ge 0$:
$ x= \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{ \left[ 2^nx \right]- 2\left[ 2^{n-1}x \right]}{2^n}$
3)This is wrong. Remind yourself that we have:
$\frac{1}{2} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$

4) Open? I have no idea what this means. Sorry.

**Update for part 3**
Consider the two following sequence:
$$ x= (1,0,0,0,0 ,....)$$
and
$$ y= (0,1,1,1,.....)$$

You can see that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(y) = \sum_{n \ge 1 } \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}= \frac{1}{2}$
Thus $f(x)=f(y)$ , while $x \ne y$

Comment: ya that was a typo!

Comment: for 4 it means does  f maps open sets to open sets?

Comment: Also , can you please elaborate 3. I am not able to understand it!

Comment: Dear Tim, <br> It seems that I was being not too polite in my post. I guess I was having a bad day. Concerning your question, I'll update quickly point 3.